# Как добавить данные в БД через форму

Tags: php

Помогите найти ошибку, есть подключение, есть запрос на добавление, есть форма, но почему то код не работает ,внизу  два кода, первый код форма регистрации написаный на HTML а второй PHP ,где я пытаюсь добавить данные В БД которые ввел пользователь

```
form action="action_page.php">
<div class="container">
    <center>
        <h1>Registrare</h1></center>
    <p>Completati toate campurile.</p>
    <hr>

    <label for="nume"><b>Nume_Copilului</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Introduceti numele copilului" name="nume" required>

    <label for="prenume"><b>Prenume_Copilului</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Intraduceti prenume copilului" name="psw" required>

    <label for="anul nasteri"><b>Introduceti anul nasterii </b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="anul nasterii" name="anul nasterii " required>
    <label for="numele"><b>Introduceti numele parintei </b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="numele" name="numele " required>
    <label for="prenumele"><b>Introduceti prenume parintei </b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="prenumele" name="prenumele " required>
    <label for="nr de telefon"><b>Introduceti nr de telefon parintei </b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="nr de telefon" name="nr de telefon"  

<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '', 'crafti');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", 
mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
 }

mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");

if(isset($_POST['psw']))
{
$psw = $_POST['psw'];
}

if(isset($_POST['nrdetelefon']))
{
$nrdetelefon = $_POST['nr de telefon'];
}
$result = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO parinte 
 ('ID','Prenume','Nr_telefon') VALUES ( 
  '1','$psw','$nrdetelefon')");

  if ($result==true)
   {
  echo "<br>Информация в базу добавлена успешно.";
  }
  else echo "<br>Информация в базу не добавлена.";

   mysqli_close($link);

  ?>
```

Comment: ошибку для себя выводи https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php а не пустое сообщение

Comment: разное - $_POST['nrdetelefon'] $_POST['nr de telefon']

Comment: Так я и вывожу ошибку <?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', '', '', 'crafti');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", 
mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
 }

Comment: А потом `else echo "<br>Информация в базу не добавлена.";`

Comment: это вывод ошибки при подключении к БД, а тебе надо увидеть ошибку при невыполнении запроса в таблицу БД.

Comment: mysqli канул в прошлом десятилетии, не трать на него время, посмотри PDO примеры кода https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: У тебя данные каким методом передаются из формы?

Comment: Методом Post...